# How to use more than one jQuery AutoSuggest on a single page?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, autosuggest

I can use AutoSuggest jQuery plugin on my page... but how do I create more than one of them on a single page? I don't understand syntax on [this site](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin) with this example:

```
$(function(){
    $("div.someClass input").autoSuggest(data);
    $("#someID input").autoSuggest(other_data);
});
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Maybe you don't understand because you haven't read enough about how jQuery works and how selectors work in particular. You should go read up on what selectors are and how to use them in jQuery. the answers will become clear.

Comment: HI ithcy.. Ya you are right. i am very new in jquery. its very thank full to you if you provide me a simple demo example.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say, beacuse it is not clear what you do not understand. Anyway, you select your inputs via a CSS-like selector

```
$('css selector here')
```

and then you just call the method `autoSuggest` on it, like

```
$('css selector here').autoSuggest();
```

If you want to do this with more than one field, just repeat.

```
$('css selector here').autoSuggest();
$('another css selector here').autoSuggest();
```

You can pass an object storing some options as a parameter to `autoSuggest`.

Comment: Hi Andrea . Thanks for your reply. so i was not adding more details abt my prob. now i am explaining the hole issue..

Comment: I actually see the same question as before, with no additional details. Is my answer enough? What are the parts of my answer that you don't understand?